# Why isn't glob * wildcard working in python subprocess.call?

Tags: python, subprocess, wildcard, glob

I want to use glob pattern like this in subprocess.call function:

```
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "output*"])
ls: cannot access output*: No such file or directory
2
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "output\*"])
ls: cannot access output\*: No such file or directory
2
```

But cannot use `glob(*)` pattern after filename `"output"` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globbing (expanding the *) is a function of your shell. You need to add the `shell=True` parameter to execute the command through a shell interpreter.

```
subprocess.call("ls output*", shell=True)
```